# How to create XML file without XML opening tags

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm using PHP to create an XML file, this was quite challenging for me as I'm not an expert when it comes to PHP, however the output is not as desired. Question: How do I create my desired output?

**Clarification:** I need this because this file will get merged into another dynamically created XML file where the XML opening tags would cause the following error: `XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document`.

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
  <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="saturday"/>
  <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="sunday"/>
  <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="sunday"/>
  <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="sunday"/>
  <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="today"/>
</items>
```

**Desired output:** (I know this is not valid XML but it is still called a `.xml` file per definition).

```
<page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="saturday"/>
<page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="sunday"/>
<page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="sunday"/>
<page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="sunday"/>
<page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="today"/>
```

**PHP:**

```
$xmldata = new SimpleXMLElement('<items />');

for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['data']); $i++) {
  $xmlpage = $xmldata->addChild('page');
  $xmlpage->addAttribute('description', 'template4');
  $xmlpage->addAttribute('type', '4');
  $xmlpage->addAttribute('duration', '5000');
  $xmlpage->addAttribute('on', $_POST['data']['bday' . $i . '']['when']);
}

$xmldata->asXML('xml/playlistbdays.xml');
```

**I tried:**

`$xmldata = new SimpleXMLElement('');` which gives an error saying: `String could not be parsed as XML`.

Comment: You may be better off just building it up as a string - why bother with the SimpleXMLElement when you don't want a proper XML file.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). Why do you need such an output? This is your proposed *Y* solution to an *X* problem you do not explain.

Comment: @Barskey ... for future readers and best practices standards, I must implore you to not treat XML docs as string per the accepted answer below. Please explain why you need a root-less XML.

Comment: @Parfait Good point, added some clarification.

Comment: Ha-ha! Exactly what I thought. Classic XY Problem. You absolutely do not need to remove header. You can easily merge XML by parsing the docs with `load` and use PHP's [importNode](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) or XSLT's [document()](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_document.html). Next time explain the **full** problem for robust answers, possibly why you received a downvote due to hacky need.

Comment: @Parfait I don't see why you would call this an "XY Problem", I just wanted to know how to add data to a file in a certain format. I understand your previous comment and therefore I clarified why I needed this, for future readers. Also, I'm not able to access any back-end type of stuff to "merge XML by parsing the docs with load and use PHP's importNode or XSLT's document()". So that wouldn't be a solution in this case.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) because your proposed solution would be refined using a DOM answer (not scrapping off the declaration header) had you provided the full scope of your problem per your recent clarification. See link above where example OP simply needs to parse JSON but asks an attempt at string split/slice.

Comment: As for *back-end*, since you are using PHP (even accepted answer uses PHP), both solutions I mention is possible. Please post the larger, dynamic XML and how you need this smaller portion merged so I can provide such an answer. Your actual question should have been *how do I merge an XML into a dynamically generated XML?*

Comment: @Parfait My question was: "How to create XML file without XML opening tags" Whether the XML is valid or not, the answer I accepted works exactly like I wanted it to, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could replace data in the string before to save it:

```
$str = $xmldata->asXML(); // get as string instead of saving file
$str = str_replace(['<?xml version="1.0"?>','<items>','</items>'],'',$str); // remove tags you don't want.
file_put_contents('xml/playlistbdays.xml', trim($str)) ; // save file
```

Answer (score 0):

Since OP's overall aim is to merge XML documents (*this file will get merged into another dynamically created XML file*), consider PHP's [importNode](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.importnode.php) to merge XML files without needing to strip xml declaration header. Below example will import *items* into an *orders* xml:

```
$input_str = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
              <orders>
                <order_id>41412</order_id>
              </orders>';

$input = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); 
$input->loadXML($input_str);

$items_str = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
              <items>
                <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="saturday"/>
                <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="sunday"/>
                <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="sunday"/>
                <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="sunday"/>
                <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="today"/>
              </items>';

$items = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8'); 
$items->loadXML($items_str);

$new_node = $input->importNode($items->documentElement, TRUE);    
$input->documentElement->appendChild($new_node);

echo $input->saveXML();
#    <?xml version="1.0"?>
#    <orders>
#       <order_id>41412</order_id>
#       <items>
#         <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="saturday"/>
#         <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="sunday"/>
#         <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="sunday"/>
#         <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="sunday"/>
#         <page description="template4" type="4" duration="5000" on="today"/>
#       </items>
#   </orders>
```